# Gdal RasterizeLayer Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, rasterization

I'm attempting to rasterize a layer of a raster by using the different features inside a shapefile(In this case the different features are lines).

The problem I am running into is that RasterizeLayer does not like it when I pass it a feature rather than the layer. My code is below:

```
line_ds = ogr.Open(r"Lines.shp")
lyr=line_ds.GetLayer()    

for feat in lyr:
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(
                        target_ds,  # raster file
                        [1],  #My raster band
                        feat, #The feature in the shapeful
                        burn_values=[0] # my burn values
                        )
```

This is a fairly standard piece of code that I have used before, but only when using whole shapefiles rather than the individual features.

Also I am trying to invert the rasterization, but RasterizeLayer doesn't seem to have an option for this, I have tired adding in:

```
options=["INVERSE=TRUE"]
```

and

```
inverse=True
```

does anyone know if there is a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have to create a layer in memory to pass to rasterizLayer, something like -

```
# Create a temporary vector layer in memory
mem_drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('Memory')
mem_ds = mem_drv.CreateDataSource('out')
mem_layer = mem_ds.CreateLayer('poly', srs=srcproj, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
mem_poly = ogr.Feature(mem_layer.GetLayerDefn())
mem_poly.SetGeometryDirectly(feat.GetGeometryRef())
mem_layer.CreateFeature(mem_poly)
```

then pass mem_layer into the rasterizeLayer. [example line328](https://github.com/brclark-usgs/zonepy/blob/master/zonepy/zn.py)